# Help John watch movies!

Tags: code-golf, string, array, sorting

## Introduction

So John finally has his holidays! And what better could he do than watching some movies. He indeed has a lot of movies to watch, but he is unable to decide which one to watch first. He has a list of movies, each in the format: `<Movie name> (<Year>)`. So he makes a simple set of rules to decide his order of watching movies.

1) The first preference is given to the release year. If a movie released a year or earlier than others, then he would watch them first.

2) If two or more movies released in the same year, and one of them begins with a number, then he would prefer to watch that movie first.

3) If two or more movies released in the same year begin with a number as well, then the movie which comes first on the original list would be watched first.

4) If two or more movies released in the same year begin with a letter, then the movie beginning with a letter which comes earlier in the English alphabet will be chosen first. If two movies begin with the same letter, then the one containing a lesser number of characters in the movie name(including spaces) will be chosen first.

5) If the number of characters is also same, then the movie which comes later in the original list would be watched first.

Well, what a great set of rules indeed. Now the challenge.

## Challenge

The input will be a list of movies, i.e, strings - all following the specified format, and you need to output the sorted list, following the above stated rules. Be case insensitive , i.e, treat both uppercase and lower case characters equally and assume all inputs to be valid, and the list will contain no duplicate elements. Also, every character in the movie name is either a letter, or a number and there are blank spaces only in between. You can assume the release year is 4 digits long.

## Examples

```
Input
Output

['The Town (2010)', 'The Prestige (2006)', 'The Departed (2006)'] 
['The Departed (2006)', 'The Prestige (2006)', 'The Town (2010)']

['Hello (2001)', '15 minutes (2001)', '25 Minutes (2002)']
['15 minutes (2001)', 'Hello (2001)', '25 Minutes (2002)']

['15 (1960)', '25 days (1960)']
['15 (1960)', '25 days (1960)']

['Jjjj (2004)', 'Hello (2004)']
['Hello (2004)', 'Jjjj (2004)']

['all gone (2018)', 'Be careful (2018)']
['all gone (2018)', 'Be careful (2018)']

['Be careful (2018)', 'all gone (2018)']
['all gone (2018)', 'Be careful (2018)']
```

## Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) , so the shortest code wins!

Comment: "i.e. be case in-sensitive" - does this mean "treat upper and lowercase characters from the input as equal" or does it mean "you may assume input will always be in a single case" or does it mean "it does not matter how you compare different cases" or does it mean something else? (none of the examples help decipher it)

Comment: @JonathanAllan Sorry for confusion. I have made it clear in my post now.

Comment: @JonathanAllan I think "case insensitive" says it all. In addition to that, `<Movie name>` and all the examples are mixed case.

Comment: @Titus it does not say it all - it can be interpreted in multiple ways and is therefore ambiguous. The fact that none of the examples shows lowercase letters in the first position means they don't help explain. At least one of the answers here treats `B` as less than `a`, which according to the post clarification is incorrect, so others made assumptions about the interpretation.

Comment: @Titus the clarification affected three of the four answers.

Comment: @JonathanAllan added examples

Comment: It was autocorrect. I just realised it when editing finished. Fixed now

Comment: Is the output format relaxed (i.e. can I print additional stuff)?

Comment: @Titus depends. Like what stuff.

Comment: @ManishKundu look at [my TiO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ffa4b9927b9a94b7e8546da64bb3adda481dc43f)

Comment: @Titus yes, that's acceptable.

Comment: I feel like this isn't a complete test suite for all rules, but then again it may be because I can't think of the exception off the top of my head.

Comment: Figured it out... I want this test case please: `['21 Jump Street (2012)', '210 Jump Street (2012)', '22 Jump Street (2012)']`

Comment: I'm not sure what order that needs to be in, right now I'm thinking `21,22,210`, and if that's the case all answers fail.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn Order remains same. Rule 3

Comment: @ManishKundu misunderstood, I thought you meant the lower number comes first.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 115 bytes

```python
lambda a:sorted(a[::-1],key=lambda s:(s.split()[-1],-("/"<s[0]<":"),a.index(s)*("/"<s[0]<":"),s[0].lower(),len(s)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY5BT4MwGIbv/IoGD2sXhi1uS2y2mwdjYuJht8qhhm9bsSuE1kx@PQIRqQS9Nc/79P3esnbnwtw1x/1ro@XlLZNIcltUDjIsBecrlkbvUO@/M8uxjW2plcNEdNkKh7fhzgqa7kIekkjGymTwiS1ZTpLuFeviChUmkQbTKoQ0ZaWMw0csFoczoENxNQgnlFGyiFCPXiqwTp2gw3T7gx@glN3IAaeEBDdIzGb/N/k30yAYBz2C1kUvs15mG3RR5sOB9WCyQc8eTMYls/q0c@a7P6HtwOx@Swc3k7UdiHfnb8cve8rzvL@ynkxZj2W/YCv5f9LmCw)

-11 bytes thanks to spec change (thanks Jonathan Allan for pointing it out)
-6 bytes thanks to Lynn

Comment: I believe that since it has been confirmed that the year is guaranteed to be four digits that you could replace `int(s.split()[-1][1:-1])` with `s.split()[-1]`

Comment: @JonathanAllan cool, thanks!

Comment: A new rule clarification has made this solution invalid (it should be case-insensitive).

Comment: Unfortunately (due to clarification of the intended meaning of "be case in-sensitive") this fails for `['all low (2018)','B movie (2018)']`

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer thanks fixed

Comment: @JonathanAllan fixed

Comment: Instead of adding the final tie-break in the tuple you can simply sort `a[::-1]`, as `sorted` performs a stable sort. [115 bytes](https://tio.run/##fY5BT4MwGIbv/IoGD2sXhi1uS2y2mwdjYuJht8qhhm9bsSuE1kx@PQIRqQS9Nc/79P3esnbnwtw1x/1ro@XlLZNIcltUDjIsBecrlkbvUO@/M8uxjW2plcNEdNkKh7fhzgqa7kIekkjGymTwiS1ZTpLuFeviChUmkQbTKoQ0ZaWMw0csFoczoENxNQgnlFGyiFCPXiqwTp2gw3T7gx@glN3IAaeEBDdIzGb/N/k30yAYBz2C1kUvs15mG3RR5sOB9WCyQc8eTMYls/q0c@a7P6HtwOx@Swc3k7UdiHfnb8cve8rzvL@ynkxZj2W/YCv5f9LmCw)!

Answer (score 2):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 108 bytes

```
func[b][s: copy[]foreach m b[append/only s reverse split m"("]foreach m sort/all s[print rejoin[m/2"("m/1]]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY7NqsIwEEb3PsXQVV21KSro@i4uFwQRdyGL2E6vKfkjE5U@fU2rouhyzpz55gvYDHtsgItZuxnas635UXDaQO18z0XrAsr6BAaOXHqPtimc1T0QBLxgIATyWkUwWZ69yeRCLKTWQNwHZWOyO6csN0WVRFMwIcTQAs8OJ4SDu1rIq5KV8wwmsgtIUf3jSMvVk/6glyGmrg8qZvfssXqK@kWt3bRj4wVbglH2HJFerFrC9o1VXxnpKGfrVfmQG9nTE3yYf13XTSGL0X39TqMYbg)

### Explanation:

```
f: func[b] [                                 the argument is a block of strings
    s: copy []                               prepare an empty block
    foreach m b [                            for each string in the input block
       append/only s reverse split m "("     split it on "(" and append in reversed order
    ]  
    foreach m sort/all s [                   sort the new block
       print rejoin[m/2 "(" m/1]             and print it in the right order
    ]
]
```

Red's `sort/all` (sort function with refinement all) performs a stable sort, comparing all the fields of a compound argument:

```
sort/all [[1 2 3 1] [1 1 6] [2 1 3] [1 2 3 4]]
== [[1 1 6] [1 2 3 1] [1 2 3 4] [2 1 3]]
```

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, <s>231 115</s> 113 bytes

PHP sort stabilized by using keys including the position

```php
while($s=$argv[++$i])$a[substr($s,-6).($s<A?:$s&_).str_pad($s<A?$i:$argc-$i,$argc,0,0)]=$s;ksort($a);print_r($a);
```

Run with `php -nr '<code>' 'movie1 (year1)' 'movie2 (year2)' ...` or [try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ffa4b9927b9a94b7e8546da64bb3adda481dc43f).

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>95</s> <s>87</s> 85 bytes

-2 thanks to [Wheat Wizard](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56656/wheat-wizard)

```r
function(v)v[order(unlist(regmatches(v,gregexpr("[0-9]{4}",v))),tolower(v),nchar(v))]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZA9a8MwEED3/IojS3SggG2c0ECn0qEUCh2yhQzCPn8hS0aSnYbS3@7KArdpY03S495DkhkLeNyORa8yV2vFBhxO2uRkWK9kbR0zVLbCZRVZNvDSn@ijM2x9iraH82f6teYDInKnpb54aUCuskpMGzyPjtoOfB5CKWObY0Vw1BcFLIniCDccAno3ZF1d0oSj/Q9@pk4YR/mMkcMK/iyffCEpdZiIgxjvoK1V78jewGQHbzcwmVr3Ka@y@LCPZiUXVzuTpfnXpmlCLw3G703S5XkhJZRahWfGD8F5IsiEoaKXM1wS76e8@r@GuJKi6@SVTd/OocBx/AY)

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site! I don't know R so I might be wrong here but I don't think you need the `f=`.  It looks like you are making an anonymous function and assigning it to a variable.  If this is an anonymous function that can be called in line you can get rid of the assignment.

Comment: you're right, it worked thanks!

Comment: What is the purpose of `tolower` ?

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 58 bytes

```perl6
*.sort({~m/\(\d+/,/^\d/??(0,$++)!!(1,.uc.ord,.chars,$--)})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Zc5BS8MwFMDxs/sUGRSa2CxNylaUIQPxIILgYbd1SmjSrSVtRtIiQ/Sr1yUjOvT6e//3koM0Kh/bI4gqcDdeE6tNDz@@2rSAhUhSnL4WIl2tIMVRkqDpFDJMhpJoIzAp99xYHM1m6BONy4nl7gqM3hBpdN3BGIMYgUqbydUmXu8lWOv3DsCMMorczNGLkbavd9IxzX/4QR646aUIvMXuxqNUSntivmQL0Nbd0Et7gdkCPF9gFpZPMWS3OQ2R4Ecb5Fw8NU3jd@a@@X1tHgquFNjpzv@W3fjqXoKSG1kNKuA5/e@n@O/@djl@Aw)

Comment: You can use `.uc` instead of `.uc.ord`. Also you could use `<(` to ignore the `\(` as in `/ \( <( \d+/` would return `2010` instead of `(2010`. Since movies have only ever been produced in 4 digit years what you have is shorter and works.

Comment: @BradGilbertb2gills `.uc.ord` is required to only sort on the first letter. An equally short alternative is `m/./.uc`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 35 bytes

```
³i
ḲṪ$ḊṖV;1ịeØDƲ×Çṭ1Ɗ;Œlḷ/$;L;ÇN$µÞ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///Q5kyuhzs2Pdy5SuXhjq6HO6eFWRs@3N2deniGy7FNh6cfbn@4c63hsS7ro5NyHu7Yrq9i7WN9uN1P5dDWw/P@H26P/P8/Wj0kI1UhJL88T0HDyMDQQFNdRwEsFFCUWlySmZ4KEjYwgwu7pBYkFpWkpsCEYwE)

-4 bytes thanks to Mr. Xcoder

Comment: Perhaps [34 bytes?](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjk0Pd65Sebij6@HOaWHWhg93d6cenuFybNPh6Yc2Z6o83LnW8FgXWFjF2scaJOSncmjr4Xn/D7dH/v8frR6SkaoQkl@ep6BhZGBooKmuowAWCihKLS7JTE8FCRuYwYVdUgsSi0pSU2DCsQA)

Comment: And [33 bytes using a helper link](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///Q5kyuhzs2Pdy5SuXhjq6HO6eFWRs@3N2deniGy7FNh6cfbn@4c63hsS6woIq1j/Xhdj@VQ1sPz/t/uD3y//9o9ZCMVIWQ/PI8BQ0jA0MDTXUdBbBQQFFqcUlmeipI2MAMLuySWpBYVJKaAhOOBQA) (saves a byte from the 34-byte version, but if that’s not valid, then you can use these in your solution to get 35). Other than this, you can use ``ḷ\`` instead of `1i$` to save another byte.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder It's `ḷ/`, not ``ḷ\``. ``ḷ\`` is the same as `ḷ/WẋLƲ`.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer I don’t think it matters here though.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer not sure it makes a difference, but thanks, I fixed it

Comment: @HyperNeutrino The difference is that, for example, `5,1,6,2,3ḷ/` will result in `5`, while ``5,1,6,2,3ḷ\`` will result in `[5, 5, 5, 5, 5]`.

Comment: A new rule clarification has made this solution invalid (it should be case-insensitive).

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer ._. fixed

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>28 26 25</s>  24 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

-1 thanks to Erik the Outgolfer (use a zip to replace pair then transpose)

```
µḲṚż>”<aŒlƲḢO;L;⁹iNƊȧ\ðÞ
```

A monadic link taking and returning lists of lists of characters.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///Q1oc7Nj3cOevoHrtHDXNtEo9Oyjm26eGORf7WPtaPGndm@h3rOrE85vCGw/P@H27X1n/UtObopIc7Z/z/H60ekpGqEJJfnqegYWRgaKCprqMAFgooSi0uyUxPBQkbmMGFXVILEotKUlOQhD2ATsgH8w3BfENThdzMvNKS1GIkQSNTBV8kQSOwYHBBanJmYo6Cc2Ixsj1AAzQMLc0MYBpTEiuLkUQQ9pmA@V5ZWVlIXKdUheTEotS00hywjyzAgok5OQrp@XmpMKFYAA)** - footer reformats the result like the input (which is interpreted as a list of lists of characters)

...or see a [test-suite](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///Q1oc7Nj3cOevoHrtHDXNtEo9Oyjm26eGORf7WPtaPGndm@h3rOrE85vCGw/P@H91zuP1R0xptfSBxdNLDnTNUgAwgigTirEeN@w5tO7Tt///oaPWQjFSFkPzyPAUNIwNDA011HQWwUEBRanFJZnoqSNjADC7sklqQWFSSmgITjlXQUYhW9wA6Lx8sZAhWaWiqkJuZV1qSWowkaGSq4IskaATUDNILVKthaGlmAFOTklhZDBMBK/DKysoC6zABK0HYZQJVkJiTo5Cenwd2qqEFWJFTqkJyYlFqWmkOTBCsElMYqBZde2wsAA)

#### How?

```
µḲṚż>”<aŒlƲḢO;L;⁹iNƊȧ\ðÞ - Link: list of lists of characters, X
                                                     e.g. ["RV (2006)", "iChannel (2006)", "300 (2006)"]
                      ðÞ - sort by the following ðyadic key function (right is now X)
µ                        - ...start a monadic chain (left is now an item in X):
 Ḳ                       -   split at spaces              ["RV","(2006)"] / ["iChannel","(2006)"] / ["300","(2006)"]
  Ṛ                      -   reverse                      ["(2006)","RV"] / ["(2006)","iChannel"] / ["(2006)","300"]
          Ʋ              -   last four links as a monad:
     ”<                  -     literal '<' character (resides between digits*  and alphas ...* also the spaces and parentheses)
    >                    -     greater than? (vectorises) [1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] / [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] / [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
        Œl               -     lower-case                 ["rv (2006)"] / ["ichannel (2006)"] / ["300 (2006)"]
       a                 -     AND (vectorises)           ['r','v',0,0,0,0,0,0,0] / ['i','c','h','a','n','n','e','l',0,0,0,0,0,0,0] / [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
   ż                     -   zip together                 [["(2006)",'r'],["RV",'v'],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0]] / [["(2006)",'i'],["iChannel",'c'],['h'],['a'],['n'],['n'],['e'],['l'],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0]] / [["(2006)",0],["300",0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0]]
           Ḣ             -   head                         ["(2006)",'r'] / ["(2006)",'i'] / ["(2006)",0]
            O            -   cast to ordinal (vectorises) [[40,50,48,48,54,41],114] / [[40,50,48,48,54,41],105] / [[40,50,48,48,54,41],0]
                         -   (Jelly cannot compare characters with integers)
              L          -   length                       9 / 15 / 10
             ;           -   concatenate                  [[40,50,48,48,54,41],114,9] / [[40,50,48,48,54,41],105,15] / [[40,50,48,48,54,41],0,10]
                   Ɗ     -   last three links as a monad:
                 i       -     1st index of item in...
                ⁹        -     chain's right argument, X    1 /  2 /  3
                  N      -     negated                     -1 / -2 / -3
               ;         -   concatenate                  [[40,50,48,48,54,41],114,9,-1] / [[40,50,48,48,54,41],105,15,-2] / [[40,50,48,48,54,41],0,10,-3]
                     \   -   cumulative reduce with:
                    ȧ    -     AND (does not vectorise)   [[40,50,48,48,54,41],114,9,-1] / [[40,50,48,48,54,41],105,15,-2] / [[40,50,48,48,54,41],0,0,0]
                         -                           i.e. max / middle / min
                         -                                so the sort, Þ, reverses this input:
                         -                                ["300 (2006)", "iChannel (2006)", "RV (2006)"]
```

Comment: Hint: `(A),(B)Z` == `(A)ż(B)`

Comment: Still a-golfin' but thanks!

Comment: [You can remove the need for `Y` :P](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43329478#43329478) (thank [Dennis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/12012/dennis) for that)

Comment: I don't think [that suggested dyadic function being called as a monad](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/h4Y5ND3fOOrrH7lHDXJvEo5Nyjm16uGORv7WP9aPGnZl@x7pOLI85vOHwvP///0erh2SkKoTkl@cpaBgZGBpoqusogIUCilKLSzLTU0HCBmZwYZfUgsSiktQUmHAsAA) works.

Comment: Right, you'd need `µḲṚż>”<aŒlƲḢO;L;⁹iNƊȧ\ðÞ`, which doesn't save any bytes. It would make the test suite a lot cleaner though.

Comment: [`µḲṚż>”<aŒlƲḢO;L;⁹iNƊȧ\ðÞ` would work as a monadic link](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///Q1oc7Nj3cOevoHrtHDXNtEo9Oyjm26eGORf7WPtaPGndm@h3rOrE85vCGw/P@//8frR6SkaoQkl@ep6BhZGBooKmuowAWCihKLS7JTE8FCRuYwYVdUgsSi0pSU5CEDU0VNAwtzYBaYwE) for the same byte count

Comment: @Dennis ^- snap